# Php Or operator doesn´works propertly

Tags: php, if-statement, operator-keyword, sentence

I´m trying to use or operator in a php sentence but only validate the first condition, what´s wrong?

````
if ($_SESSION['user_id'] != 4 || $_SESSION['rol'] != 1) 
{
//exit
}else{
  //do something
}```
````

Comment: the conditions are right and wrote correctly. There's something wrong about the expectations you have on those $_SESSION values. You should dump that variable and see the values to understand why your condition is failing. But anyway thinking about the meaning, you are checking if the user is a given one OR has not a given role. Of course it will exit also when the userid is 4 if it doesn't have that role because it's an OR condition.

Comment: Possibly short-circuit evaluation?

Comment: What is the actual content of `$_SESSION['user_id']` and `$_SESSION['rol']` and what is the expected result?

Comment: $_SESSION['user_id'] = 1 , $_SESSION['rol'] , the problem was the !=  , thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should invert the condition in this way:

```
if ($_SESSION['user_id'] == 4 || $_SESSION['rol'] == 1) 
  //it's ok
else
  //exit
```

Because otherwise if the user_id is 4 it will otherwise fail if it doesn't have the role expected